# Reading data using post

Tags: php, html, http, post, get

Consider following html page: 
index.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If GET is used for reading the data let's say "name" then following is understandable: 
welcome.php

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When POST is meant for writing the data How is it possible to read the "name" using POST? Why should the following work?

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: POST is hidden. GET is not. In the long run - it's the same thing.

Comment: Why do you expect POST should work any differently than GET?

Comment: so that means I can use post for getting data & get for writing data?

Comment: @ayvahb Yes, you technically can. The only difference is the way the values are set, GET variables appear in the URL bar and can be easily changed by the user who is loading the page. With POST variables, there is no way for the user to change them for a normal in-browser requests, but they could still potentially send a POST request some other way with whatever variables they want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add a name in your submit input `<input name="submit" type="submit">`
Second into welcome.php add `if(isset($_GET["submit"])){ $submit = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['submit']); }` 
and then use `Welcome <?php echo $submit; ?>`
i suggest to use preg_replace if you want to pass values from page to page